# Unity3D C#: Spawner keeps instantiating more than assigned values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my spawner code I'm trying to assign the instantiating limit to each wave by making it customizable.

The first wave is correct but 2nd wave gets one more spawned object than assigned and it doesn't follow the `rateOfSpawn`

Maybe its not updating its values from `wave`?

Thank you.

```
public Wave[] waves;
[HideInInspector]
public int waveIndex = 0;
private int totalObjectsInWave;
[HideInInspector]
public int destroyedObjectsInWave;

private void OnEnable()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
}

IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitStartTime);

    Wave wave = waves[waveIndex];

    while (allowSpawning)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < waves.Length; w++)
        {
            GetComponent<Gravity>().velocityOfInfluence = wave.speedOfEnemy;

            totalObjectsInWave = 0;
            totalObjectsInWave = wave.amountOfTiny + wave.amountOfSmall + wave.amountOfLarge;

            for (int t = 0; t < wave.amountOfTiny; t++)
            {
                SpawnTiny(); // Instantiates

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / wave.rateOfSpawn);
            }

            for (int s = 0; s < wave.amountOfSmall; s++)
            {
                SpawnSmall(); // Instantiates

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / wave.rateOfSpawn);
            }

            for (int l = 0; l < wave.amountOfLarge; l++)
            {
                SpawnLarge(); // Instantiates

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / wave.rateOfSpawn);
            }

            yield return new WaitUntil(() => destroyedObjectsInWave == totalObjectsInWave);
            {
                waveIndex++;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenWaves);
            }
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
public float rateOfSpawn;
public float speedOfEnemy;

public int amountOfTiny;
public int amountOfSmall;
public int amountOfLarge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Wave wave = waves[waveIndex];
>
> while (allowSpawning) { ... }
> ```

You never break out of this loop in order to get a different `Wave`.